# Format function not working when fill data to list box by sql select statement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

In Access 2003, programming with VBA.

I have a list box to fill data with two columns.
One column is `ID` and the other column is `Name`.
I want the 4 digit format on the `ID` column

I try at list box' Row Source Properties

I write select sql statment like this

```
select format([ID],'0000'), Name from myTable
```

It doesn't work.

When I remove format function, it works.

I want to fill the data with the required format

Comment: By "It doesn't work", what do you mean? It shows ID without formatting. It doesn't list anything in the list box? You get an error?

Comment: Note, using `Name` as a column name is not a great idea as NAME is a reserved word in MS Access. It can cause you lots of grief later on. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335

Answer (score 1):

I've only got 2007 here, so it *might* be a version difference....

Depending on what you mean by "it doesn't work", one of my answers has to be "Yes, it does". My test form did display the formatted ID field correctly.

However, it's no longer the `ID` field in the control--it's now `Expr1`, so this does break binding. If you want your display as you described, but still want the control bound to the `ID` column, try this:

First modify your `Row Source` to be:

```
select ID, Format([ID],'0000') As FormattedID, [Name] As SomeName from myTable
```

(and while you're at it, change the name of Name if you can--I've aliased it in case you don't have control over the table design). Then set `Bound Column` to 1, `Columns` to 3 and `Column Widths` to `0";1";1"`. This will hide the bound `ID` but display the formatted one to the user.

Comment: Now, i found format function in other forms works well, but it doesn't work in one form. When I removed format function in SQL statement, this form run correctly. After inserting format function in SQL statement, I got this error.                                 <Path> is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides. (Error 3044)